# Result of select query for setting value of update query does not work

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an update query in MS Access; for setting value of update query I have used a select query for which I am sure the result is unique, but I get an error

```
SET asbuilt_list.commented_sheet =
       Nz((SELECT [pages]
           FROM [tbl_transmittal_discipline_poi_max] AS T1
           WHERE (T1.[owner document number] = asbuilt_list.[doc])
             AND (T1.poi = "cmn" )), 0)
```

This is the error I get:

> operation must use an updateable query

My update query is this:

```
UPDATE asbuilt_list
INNER JOIN tbl_transmittal_discipline_poi_max ON asbuilt_list.doc = tbl_transmittal_discipline_poi_max.[owner document number]
SET asbuilt_list.commented_sheet =
       Nz((SELECT [pages]
           FROM [tbl_transmittal_discipline_poi_max] AS T1
           WHERE (T1.[owner document number] = asbuilt_list.[doc])
             AND (T1.poi = "cmn" )), 0)
WHERE 
    (((asbuilt_list.description ) NOT LIKE "*isometric*")
     AND ((asbuilt_list.doc) NOT LIKE "*ls*")
     AND ((asbuilt_list.discipline) <> "ppd"))
      OR ((( sbuilt_list.description) IS NULL)
          AND ((asbuilt_list.discipline) IS NULL));
```

Comment: Need to see your schema. When you execute the inner join are you getting records that uniquely identify records in asbuilt_list? If not, the query is not updateable.

Comment: 1)  There is a table `sbuilt_list` listed in the WHERE clause.  Is this a typo, missing the starting `a`?  2)  Why are you joining on `tbl_transmittal_discipline_poi_max` AND separately linking the tables in an embedded subquery?  I have used the subquery "trick" before to avoid the same error, but I really don't see a need to do both.  There is no dependence on `tbl_transmittal_discipline_poi_max` in the main query, so it seems redundant and could be contributing to the error if the join does not product *unique* `asbuilt_list` rows as nicomp said.